# Subquery and selecting oldest rows for multiple foreign keys in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery

I have two tables:

```
product (idproduct, name, description, tax)

product_storage (idstorage, idproduct, added, quantity, price)
```

for each product it could be different price and oldest are "first-to-sell"

for example in storage I have:

```
1, 1, 2010-01-01,  0, 10.0
2, 1, 2010-01-02,  0, 11.0
3, 1, 2010-01-03, 10, 12.0
4, 2, 2010-01-04,  0, 12.0
5, 2, 2010-01-05, 10, 11.0
6, 2, 2010-01-06, 10, 13.0
7, 3, 2010-01-07, 10, 14.0
8, 3, 2010-01-08, 10, 16.0
9, 3, 2010-01-09, 10, 13.0
```

and now I need to select all products with current price, which is in the oldest row in product_storage where quantity > 0 for each product:

```
SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, p.tax,
       (SELECT s.price
        FROM product_storage s
        WHERE s.idproduct=p.idproduct AND s.quantity > 0
        ORDER BY s.added ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS price
FROM product p;
```

works fine, but it doesn't when I want to calculate price with tax in query:

```
SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, p.tax,
       (SELECT s.price
        FROM product_storage s
        WHERE s.idproduct=p.idproduct AND s.quantity > 0
        ORDER BY s.added ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS price,
        (price * (1 + tax/100)) AS price_with_tax
FROM product p;
```

MySQL says:

```
Unknown column 'price' in 'field list'
```

**Update**

Using subquery as a table almost solves problem (look at answers) - the only question now is how to select oldest rows from product_storage for multiple foreign keys (one and only one for each idproduct).

**Update 2**

Thanks to cmptrgeekken for great solution :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the `price doesn't exist` error is because you can't reference aliased columns in the column list. To fix this, store the `price` value in a user-defined variable and reference that, like so:

```
SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, p.tax,
       @price := (SELECT s.price
        FROM product_storage s
        WHERE s.idproduct=p.idproduct AND s.quantity > 0
        ORDER BY s.added ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS price,
        (@price * (1 + tax/100)) AS price_with_tax
FROM product p;
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work better using the subquery as a table:

```
SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, p.tax, s.price, (s.price * (1 + p.tax/100)) as price_with_tax
FROM product p
INNER JOIN (SELECT idproduct, price
        FROM product_storage
        WHERE quantity > 0) s
ON p.idproduct = s.idproduct
INNER JOIN (SELECT idproduct, MIN(added) min
        FROM product_storage
        GROUP BY idproduct) f
ON s.idproduct = f.idproduct AND s.added = f.min
```

Edit: Updated because tax is in the other table, so I had to move that calculation's location.

Edit 2: OK, changed things around again to try to filter the product_storage table properly.

Comment: "Unknown column 'tax' in 'field list'"

Comment: maybe I should denormalize tables and repeat tax data in product_storage?

Comment: @Marek: Oh whoops, tax is in the other table isn't it.

Comment: yeah... but still it's not ok - with LIMIT 1 subquery is a table with 1 row and without it has all rows WHERE quantity > 0... in particular it has more than 1 row for each product (with different prices) - look at my first answer to this question ;)

Comment: @Marek: I should have thought of that.  It's possible to fix it, but the query may become more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

this works almost fine:

```
SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, p.tax,
       sub.price, (sub.price * (1+tax/100)) as price_with_tax
FROM product p,
    (SELECT s.idproduct, s.price
     FROM product_storage s
     WHERE quantity > 0
     ORDER BY added ASC) sub
WHERE p.idproduct=sub.idproduct
```

but all rows from product_storage are returned for each product :/

Answer (score 0):

As far as MySQL is concerned, that last occurrence of the word "price" is referring to a field in Product p, hence the error.  You need to refer again to the aliased subquery right above that:

```
SELECT p.idproduct, p.name, p.tax,
       (SELECT s.price
        FROM product_storage s
        WHERE s.idproduct=p.idproduct AND s.quantity > 0
        ORDER BY s.added ASC
        LIMIT 1) AS price,
        (       (SELECT s.price
        FROM product_storage s
        WHERE s.idproduct=p.idproduct AND s.quantity > 0
        ORDER BY s.added ASC
        LIMIT 1) * (1 + tax/100)) AS price_with_tax
FROM product p;
```

Comment: there isn't any 'price' field in 'product' table - are you sure that this repeated subquery isn't calculated again?

Comment: That was the point that I failed to make clear in my post.  You can't use your aliased field to calculate the tax value, because MySQL is looking for a 'price' column in the Product table.  So what I wrote explicitly asks for the calculated value from Product_Storage again.

At any rate, I think PowerLord's answer is altogether better (go figure.)

Answer (score 0):

First, you want to get the lowest storage id for the product(s).

```
SELECT idproduct, MIN(idstorage) idstorage FROM product_storage 
WHERE quantity>0 AND idproduct IN (#, #, ...)
GROUP BY idstorage
```

idstorage, idproduct, added, quantity, price
Then you can join on that query and the product_storage table (again), using the min storage ID, to get your product info with the correct pricing info.

```
SELECT idproduct, name, description, tax, ps.price, ps.quantity,
FROM product AS p
JOIN 
(SELECT idproduct, MIN(idstorage) idstorage FROM product_storage 
WHERE quantity>0 AND idproduct IN (#, #, ...)
GROUP BY idstorage) AS min_id
ON p.idproduct=min_id.idproduct
RIGHT JOIN product_storage AS ps ON ps.idstorage=min_id.idstorage
WHERE idproduct IN (#, #, ...)
```

Comment: "... idproduct IN (#, #, ...) ..." - idproduct isn't specified - for example I take newest products, products from category X etc.